# I need help for a LEFT JOIN SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I need help to write a simple procedure. Let me explain what I'm trying to do.

I have 3 tables

1. tJobOffer
2. tApplication
3. tApplicationStatus

I would like to create a procedure that return me a list of tJobOffer with the number of candidate that responded to this tJobOffer. Candidate is a status of my table tApplicationStatus. This table is linked to tApplication that is linked to tJobOffer. An application can be CANDIDATE / ACCEPTED / REFUSED / IGNORED / ...

I created this query :

```
    SELECT 
        [T].[JobOfferId],
        [T].[JobOfferTitle],
        COUNT([A].[ApplicationId]) AS [CandidateCount]

    FROM        [tJobOffer] AS [T]
    LEFT JOIN   [tApplication] AS [A]
        ON      [A].[JobOfferId] = [T].[JobOfferId]
    LEFT JOIN   [tApplicationStatus] AS [S]
        ON      [S].[ApplicationStatusId] = [A].[ApplicationStatusId]
        AND     [S].[ApplicationStatusTechnicalName] = 'CANDIDATE'

    GROUP BY
            [T].[JobOfferId],
            [T].[JobOfferTitle]
            --[A].[ApplicationStatusId]

    ORDER BY [T].[JobOfferTitle]
```

The result is

```
> 52ED7C67-21E1-49BB-A1F8-0601E6EED1EA  Annonce 1   0
> F26B228D-0C81-4DA8-A287-F8F997CC1F9C  Annonce 1b  0
> 9DA60B23-F113-4C7F-9707-2B90C1556D5D  Announce 25 2
> 258E11A7-79C1-47B6-8C61-413AA54E2360  Announce 3  0
> DA582383-5DF4-4E1D-837C-382371BDEF57  Announce 6  2
```

This is not correct because I only have 1 candidate for Announce 6. If a set my line

```
    --AND     [S].[ApplicationStatusTechnicalName] = 'CANDIDATE'
```

in comment the result is the same. My query seems to ignore this line. What is wrong?

EDIT --

My correct result should be

```
> 52ED7C67-21E1-49BB-A1F8-0601E6EED1EA  Annonce 1   0
> F26B228D-0C81-4DA8-A287-F8F997CC1F9C  Annonce 1b  0
> 9DA60B23-F113-4C7F-9707-2B90C1556D5D  Announce 25 2
> 258E11A7-79C1-47B6-8C61-413AA54E2360  Announce 3  0
> DA582383-5DF4-4E1D-837C-382371BDEF57  Announce 6  1
```

Comment: much better if you can add sample records with desired result aling with your question `:D`

Comment: Why are you joining `[tApplicationStatus] AS [S]` if you are not using it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
SELECT 
    [T].[JobOfferId],
    [T].[JobOfferTitle],
    COUNT([A].[ApplicationId]) AS [CandidateCount]

FROM        [tJobOffer] AS [T]
LEFT JOIN   [tApplication] AS [A]
    INNER JOIN  [tApplicationStatus] AS [S]
        ON      [S].[ApplicationStatusId] = [A].[ApplicationStatusId]
        AND     [S].[ApplicationStatusTechnicalName] = 'CANDIDATE'
    ON      [A].[JobOfferId] = [T].[JobOfferId]

GROUP BY
        [T].[JobOfferId],
        [T].[JobOfferTitle]

ORDER BY [T].[JobOfferTitle] ;
```

You could also join first the 2 "Application" tables, group by and then join the derived table with `JobOffer`:

```
SELECT 
    [T].[JobOfferId],
    [T].[JobOfferTitle],
    COALESCE([G].[Cnt], 0) AS [CandidateCount]

FROM        [tJobOffer] AS [T]
LEFT JOIN   
            ( SELECT 
                  [A].[JobOfferId],
                  COUNT(*) AS [Cnt]

              FROM        [tApplication] AS [A]
              INNER JOIN  [tApplicationStatus] AS [S]
                  ON      [S].[ApplicationStatusId] = [A].[ApplicationStatusId]
                  AND     [S].[ApplicationStatusTechnicalName] = 'CANDIDATE'

              GROUP BY
                          [A].[JobOfferId]
            ) AS [G]
    ON      [G].[JobOfferId] = [T].[JobOfferId]

ORDER BY [T].[JobOfferTitle] ;
```

Comment: Correct. Thank you. I didn't know it was possible to a join in a join.

Answer (score 1):

as per your requirement  first you need to use left join there after you have to use inner join.

try the below one

```
SELECT 
    [T].[JobOfferId],
    [T].[JobOfferTitle],
    COUNT([A].[ApplicationId]) AS [CandidateCount]

FROM        [tJobOffer] AS [T]
LEFT JOIN   [tApplication] AS [A]
    INNER JOIN   [tApplicationStatus] AS [S]
        ON      [S].[ApplicationStatusId] = [A].[ApplicationStatusId]
        AND     [S].[ApplicationStatusTechnicalName] = 'CANDIDATE'
    ON      [A].[JobOfferId] = [T].[JobOfferId]

GROUP BY
        [T].[JobOfferId],
        [T].[JobOfferTitle]

ORDER BY [T].[JobOfferTitle] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
        [T].[JobOfferId],
        [T].[JobOfferTitle],
        COUNT([A].[ApplicationId]) AS [CandidateCount]

    FROM        [tJobOffer] AS [T]
    LEFT JOIN   [tApplication] AS [A]
        ON      [A].[JobOfferId] = [T].[JobOfferId]
    LEFT JOIN   
         (SELECT ApplicationStatusId FROM [tApplicationStatus]
          WHERE  [ApplicationStatusTechnicalName] = 'CANDIDATE') [S]
        ON      [S].[ApplicationStatusId] = [A].[ApplicationStatusId]
    GROUP BY
            [T].[JobOfferId],
            [T].[JobOfferTitle]
    ORDER BY [T].[JobOfferTitle]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are asking why the rows you filtered with the ON clause of the second LEFT JOIN still show up in the final result.

If that is your question then the answer is:

The filter based on the ON predicate is not final, i.e. the ON predicate does not determine whether the row will show up in the output, only whether it will be matched with rows from the other table.

The WHERE clause on the other hand is final and is processed after the FROM clause — namely, after all table operators were processed and (in the case of outer joins), after all outer rows were produced.

Therefore, when you need a filter to be applied after outer rows are produced, and you want the filter to be final, specify the predicate in the WHERE clause.